# phonegap,cordova; barcodescanner plugin gives 'Scannig failed:Class not found' error

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans, barcode-scanner

I am using phonegap 3.4.0 with netbeans. I add [barcodeScanner](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo) pluging to my project, when
i run this code :

```
var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
                scanner.scan(function(result) {
                            alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                             }, function(error) {
                              alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                  });
```

gives the `Scannig failed:Class not found` error.

I try to solve the error with adding this lines

`<plugin name="BarcodeScanner"value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"/>`

to my `res/xml/config.xml` file. But after adding this lines and built netbeans project
the changes that i made in config.xml being revoked by netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding a line for barcodeScanner plugin to  `PROJECT_PATH/nbproject/plugins.properties`  file as follow

`com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner=https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git`

after that when i build the project netbeans automatically updated my `config.xml` and barcode scanner worked fine.